# Solve in real $x,\,\,\lfloor x^3\rfloor-3\lfloor x^2\rfloor+2\lfloor x\rfloor=0$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Solve in real $x,\,\,\lfloor x^3\rfloor-3\lfloor x^2\rfloor+2\lfloor x\rfloor=0$

My progress:

$x$ must be non negative and $x<3$
As $x\ge 3\implies \lfloor x^3\rfloor\ge\lfloor x\rfloor\lfloor x^2\rfloor\ge 3\lfloor x^2\rfloor\implies\lfloor x^3\rfloor-3\lfloor x^2\rfloor+2\lfloor x\rfloor\ge 6$

hence all solutions $\in [0,3)$

For $x\in [0,1),LHS=0-0+0=0$

For $x\in [1,\sqrt[3]2),LHS=1-3+2=0$

For $x\in [2,\sqrt[3]9),LHS=8-12+4=0$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is ur question?

Comment: Why stop at what you've done? Why not order the solutions in $[0,3)$ of $x^k=m$ for $k\in\{1,2,3\}$ and $m\in\{0,\cdots,26\}$ from smallest to lagest and see what's what in each interval $[a,b)$?